# Top2Vec model returning TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, hdbscan, top2vec

I'm trying to train a top2vec model and come up against either the issue of not having enough documents which I rectify by concatenating the dataframe with itself etc.

Then upon training the model the Type Error comes up. I can't find where the float is coming from to further investigate how to change it.

The data consists of 2 columns of string data

```
# Increase number of docs
data = [df, df, df, df, df]
df_extra = pd.concat(data)
print(len(df_extra))

# Train the top2vec model
model = Top2Vec(df_extra.values, embedding_model='universal-sentence-encoder') #,  embedding_model='universal-sentence-encoder'
```

The model runs until it hits Finding dense areas of document then throws the error.
Traceback shows possibly an issue with the clustering when it hits dbscan?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[84], line 2
      1 # Train the top2vec model
----> 2 model = Top2Vec(df_extra.values, embedding_model='universal-sentence-encoder') #,  embedding_model='universal-sentence-encoder'

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/top2vec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/top2vec/Top2Vec.py:666, in Top2Vec.__init__(self, documents, min_count, topic_merge_delta, ngram_vocab, ngram_vocab_args, embedding_model, embedding_model_path, embedding_batch_size, split_documents, document_chunker, chunk_length, max_num_chunks, chunk_overlap_ratio, chunk_len_coverage_ratio, sentencizer, speed, use_corpus_file, document_ids, keep_documents, workers, tokenizer, use_embedding_model_tokenizer, umap_args, hdbscan_args, verbose)
    663 else:
    664     raise ValueError(f"{embedding_model} is an invalid embedding model.")
--> 666 self.compute_topics(umap_args=umap_args, hdbscan_args=hdbscan_args, topic_merge_delta=topic_merge_delta)
    668 # initialize document indexing variables
    669 self.document_index = None

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/top2vec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/top2vec/Top2Vec.py:1266, in Top2Vec.compute_topics(self, umap_args, hdbscan_args, topic_merge_delta)
   1261 if hdbscan_args is None:
   1262     hdbscan_args = {'min_cluster_size': 15,
   1263                     'metric': 'euclidean',
   1264                     'cluster_selection_method': 'eom'}
-> 1266 cluster = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(**hdbscan_args).fit(umap_model.embedding_)
   1268 # calculate topic vectors from dense areas of documents
   1269 logger.info('Finding topics')

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/top2vec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/hdbscan/hdbscan_.py:1205, in HDBSCAN.fit(self, X, y)
   1195 kwargs.pop("prediction_data", None)
   1196 kwargs.update(self._metric_kwargs)
   1198 (
   1199     self.labels_,
   1200     self.probabilities_,
   1201     self.cluster_persistence_,
   1202     self._condensed_tree,
   1203     self._single_linkage_tree,
   1204     self._min_spanning_tree,
-> 1205 ) = hdbscan(clean_data, **kwargs)
   1207 if self.metric != "precomputed" and not self._all_finite:
   1208     # remap indices to align with original data in the case of non-finite entries.
   1209     self._condensed_tree = remap_condensed_tree(
   1210         self._condensed_tree, internal_to_raw, outliers
   1211     )

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/top2vec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/hdbscan/hdbscan_.py:884, in hdbscan(X, min_cluster_size, min_samples, alpha, cluster_selection_epsilon, max_cluster_size, metric, p, leaf_size, algorithm, memory, approx_min_span_tree, gen_min_span_tree, core_dist_n_jobs, cluster_selection_method, allow_single_cluster, match_reference_implementation, **kwargs)
    867         else:
    868             (single_linkage_tree, result_min_span_tree) = memory.cache(
    869                 _hdbscan_boruvka_balltree
    870             )(
   (...)
    880                 **kwargs
    881             )
    883 return (
--> 884     _tree_to_labels(
    885         X,
    886         single_linkage_tree,
    887         min_cluster_size,
    888         cluster_selection_method,
    889         allow_single_cluster,
    890         match_reference_implementation,
    891         cluster_selection_epsilon,
    892         max_cluster_size,
    893     )
    894     + (result_min_span_tree,)
    895 )

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/top2vec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/hdbscan/hdbscan_.py:80, in _tree_to_labels(X, single_linkage_tree, min_cluster_size, cluster_selection_method, allow_single_cluster, match_reference_implementation, cluster_selection_epsilon, max_cluster_size)
     78 condensed_tree = condense_tree(single_linkage_tree, min_cluster_size)
     79 stability_dict = compute_stability(condensed_tree)
---> 80 labels, probabilities, stabilities = get_clusters(
     81     condensed_tree,
     82     stability_dict,
     83     cluster_selection_method,
     84     allow_single_cluster,
     85     match_reference_implementation,
     86     cluster_selection_epsilon,
     87     max_cluster_size,
     88 )
     90 return (labels, probabilities, stabilities, condensed_tree, single_linkage_tree)

File hdbscan/_hdbscan_tree.pyx:659, in hdbscan._hdbscan_tree.get_clusters()

File hdbscan/_hdbscan_tree.pyx:733, in hdbscan._hdbscan_tree.get_clusters()

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I've read the other questions relating to this type error but not specific to top2vec so it's not clear where in this algorithm the float is emerging where it shouldn't. Any guidance appreciated...Could multiplying the documents still be leaving too little topics and thus resulting in a float perhaps?

Comment: Check the data types of the columns in `df_extra` with `df_extra.dtypes`. There might be some columns that has the `dtype` of `float64`.

Comment: This just returns object type, but I've forced all cols to str using astype(str) across the dataframe [df = df.astype(str)] so I can't see how the float is going in.

Comment: Not sure you're still looking for a solution, but I'm fairly certain the problem lies with the latest verstion of hdbscan. Try reverting to an earlier version of hdbscan/scikit-learn or install the github version of hdbscan (worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

The problem apparently is not with top2vec specifically but a combination of numpy, hdbscan and scikit-learn versions.

To resolve this issue, use the following versions:

- Python 3.10x version
- numpy==1.24.4
- hdbscan==0.8.33
- scikit-learn==1.2.1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).